# Get ScaleTransform and RotateTransform from System.Windows.Shapes.Path

Tags: wpf, scaletransform, rendertransform

I'm trying to get *RotateTransform* value (degrees) and *ScaleTransform* from code parsing XAML nodes, in this case a System.Windows.Shapes.Path.

```
<Path Data="M272,0 L0,0" Height="12.274" Canvas.Left="17.997" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" 
  StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" 
  Canvas.Top="44.53" Width="146.499" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
  <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Using *RenderTransform*, I get a *Matrix* Value and I'm not able to get angle and scaleX from that.

```
myPath.RenderTransform.Value
```

How can I get these informations?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the solution:

```
TransformGroup tg = myPath.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;

if (tg != null)
{
    // Get rotation angle
    RotateTransform rt = tg.Children[2] as RotateTransform;
    // DoSomething with rt.Angle

    // Get scale factor
    ScaleTransform st = tg.Children[0] as ScaleTransform;
    // DoSomething with st.ScaleX or st.ScaleY
}
```

Comment: Works well for me.